# Has the favourite star got rounded spikes?

Tags: discussion, design

I just noticed that the favourite star has slightly rounded spikes.
I'm quite sure they were pointy yesterday.

Is this true, and which version do you like better?

Comment: Wow, nice catch. You can spot the difference if you switch between SO and Meta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I like the rounded star, but I don't like the light gray background around it.

Its subtle but it looks like the image didn't quite get the attention it needed in Photoshop.

Its most notable on a laptop where the screen is often not perpendicular to your eyeline.

Here's a closeup:
[image]

Comment: Glad it's not just me that the background difference annoys...

Comment: ...also on SU

Comment: ...and now on SO if you force a refresh...

Comment: I didn't notice at first, but it is really there.
Maybe another manifestation of the PNG gamma problem.

Answer (score 12):

This is a travesty and I simply will not stand idly by while Royal Squadron Atwood Beta goes around rounding everything in sight. It starts with a little star here, an upvote arrow there. But what next? Soon he'll be rounding reputation scores, badge counts, IP addresses, **words**! Think of all the data we're going to lose to unscrupulous rounding.

The line has to be drawn here!

Comment: You mean the *circle* must be drawn, don't you ;)

Comment: @John Smithers: Nothing personal, but I'm going to stab you while knives are still unrounded.

Comment: You know, the Nazis had little stars they made the Jews wear.

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand what you're implying, Pesto.

Comment: @Welbog: I'm fairly certain that was an *Office Space* reference. :)

Comment: @Welbog: Looks like the cats are gone. Did you use that knife?

Comment: @John Smithers: I ate the knife, actually. The cats saw how serious I was about it that they just shut up. That's just how it is with me.

Answer (score 1):

After the initial reaction that it looks all alien and unexpected passes, I think I might actually prefer the rounded one... This doesn't provoke very strong feelings either way though, as the change is rather small.