# For rule-following sock puppets, is there a "guaranteed" way to request they be merged into a puppeteer account?

Tags: discussion, merge-accounts, sock-puppets, memes

###### Background

I am musing on the idea of carrying out an elaborate joke where I create a puppeteer account named "Dio" and then create a [rule-following](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/388985) sock puppet, using it to add value to the community over a long period, and then get it merged into the puppeteer account.

###### Research

I see there is [an official procedure for merging if you ***accidentally*** created two accounts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts), but sock puppets are not accidental.

I tried to look for a post about the process of requesting that a sock puppet be merged, but couldn't find one.

There is "[Questions about merging sock puppet accounts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/378549)", but the asker engaged in bad sock puppet behaviour and the answer didn't describe the process for requesting that a sock puppet be merged.

[This answer to the question of how sock puppets should be handled](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/57685) says:

> This depends on the severity of the abuse and the discretion of the moderator handling it. For the typical first occurrence:
> Send a warning to the primary account, and either suspend or send another warning to the secondary account or simply delete it **or merge** it into the primary account if the abuse is blatant.
> For subsequent occurrences (and first occurrences when the abuse is blatant):
> Suspend the primary account, and suspend, **merge, or** delete secondary accounts.

The answer there doesn't expand on the logic for *when* a merge is the "right choice", and I'd rather have a surefire way to get the puppet merged into the puppeteer *without* engaging in bad socket puppet related behaviour to trigger getting moderator attention.

###### Distilled Question

Is there a standard process for requesting that a sock puppet be merged into its puppeteer, and if you were a mod receiving the request, would you view such a request in the context of executing such a joke as annoying or funny, and would that affect whether you accept the merge request or kill it to kill the joke?

Comment: *would you view such a request in the context of executing such a joke as annoying or funny"* - even if it were found amusing in some way, it would still be annoying. *"would that affect whether you accept the merge request or kill it to kill the joke?"* - it would not affect whether a legitimate request is correctly handled, but it would very much affect whether you kept good will.

Comment: "an elaborate joke", what exactly would be funny about this; how is it even remotely humorous?

Comment: @ElementsinSpace https://knowyourmeme.com/memes/it-was-me-dio

Comment: "*an elaborate joke*" [we hate fun on SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/284390/241919).

Comment: 'puppeteer' is not to be confused with '[Puppeteer](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/puppeteer/)'.

Comment: There *was* [a fun time](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/52443/welbog?tab=answers&sort=newest&page=4). [Sample](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12783/has-the-favourite-star-got-rounded-spikes/12784#12784).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In *theory*, you could simply use the [contact link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/contact) to request a merger. Since you manage the accounts in question, it would be simple to confirm these are yours. At some point though, you're basically wasting CM time.

> would you view such a request in the context of executing such a joke as annoying or funny,

In *practice* though - I think this is a terrible idea. Assuming your socks are *all* following the rules perfectly. They're *really* adding value, not asking trolling questions, and there's literally no interaction between the accounts it's still likely to be disruptive for a bunch of 'productive' regular users to vanish already.

It's also fairly troublesome to actually maintain a secondary account, let alone multiple ones. I have one that I used on untrusted PCs and when I'm in an environment where I manage all my own systems, I don't use the account at all.

There's something I've heard said in unusual situations, "You aren't breaking the rules, you're breaking the community". Doing a bunch of things for a 'laugh' or an elaborate troll might seem fun but considering the way we run our communities, and the focus on useful information and less noise, seems contrary to the SE ethos of doing things.

As such, I'd discourage you from such tomfoolery.